# Prevent recursive calls in WinForm event handlers

Tags: c#, winforms

Changing `TextBox.Text` within the `TextBox.TextChanged` event can trigger a
recursive call to the same event handler. My class `EventHelper` is designed
to separate the action performed in the event handler from the mechanism that
prevents the recursive calls. The calls can be used as in:

```
public static class EventHelperTest
{
    public static void ExampleUsage()
    {
        var eventHelper = new EventHelper();

        var textBox = new TextBox();
        textBox.TextChanged += (s, e) => eventHelper.ExecuteOnce(() =>
        {
            textBox.Text = textBox.Text + "a";
        });

        textBox.Text = "trigger ";

        Debug.Assert(textBox.Text == "trigger a");
    }
}
```

where the `EventHelper` is:

```
public class EventHelper
{
    bool skip;

    public void ExecuteOnce(Action f)
    {

        if (skip)
            return;

        skip = true;
        f();
        skip = false;
    }
}
```

I am looking for a review of the `EventHelper` class.

Answer (score 2):

You can improve the `EventHelper` by *reusing* the `sender` argument so that you have only a single instance of the helper. The helper maintains a `HashSet<object>` that stores *senders* that are currently handled. This will allow you to use the return value of the `Add` method which is `false` if the `sender` already has been added an thus acts like your `skip` variable. Finally you `Remove` the `sender` from the set as if you were setting `skip` to `false`.

```
public class EventHelper
{
    private readonly ISet<object> _senders = new HashSet<object>();

    public void ExecuteOnce(object sender, Action action)
    {
        if (!_senders.Add(sender))
        {
            return;
        }

        action();
        _senders.Remove(sender);
    }
}
```

You would now call it with one more parameter:

```
eventHelper.ExecuteOnce(s, () =>
```

---

As far as the code is concerned you should always use `{}` and perhaps parameter names longer then a single letter `f`.